# Jquery динамически назначить атрибут selected для option-a

Tags: jquery, html, select

html

```
 <select name="status" id="status">
    <option disabled selected>...</option>
    <option value="Shipped">Shipped</option>
    <option value="Resolved">Resolved</option>
    <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
    <option value="On Hold">On Hold</option>
    <option value="Disputed">Disputed</option>
    <option value="In Process">In Process</option>
</select>
```

jquery

```
    //option с этим значением ,нужно сделать selected
var needle = 'In Process';
$('#status > option').each(function(k,v){

         //сначала уберем selected у option-a со значением "..."

         if(k == 0) $(v).removeAttr('selected');

        //когда искомый эл-т найден, назначим его выбранным

        if($(v).val() == needle) $(v).attr('selected',true);

});
```

Проблема в том ,что option  с атрибутом select не отображается первым в списке.Хотя искомому элементу назаначается select...

Answer (score 1):

Для selected следует использовать не attr/removeAttr, а prop (чтоб снять флаг, второй аргумент равен false). И легче менять не selected у option, а value у select: `$('#status').val(needle)`.
И даже так: выбранный элемент не будет и не должен отображаться первым в списке. Если хотите делать сортировку при выборе, то тут уже придется попотеть сильнее, т.к. это не является стандартным поведением select.

Comment: "...не является стандартным поведением select."
Я думал , что это тривиальная задача.Мне всего-то нужно средствами jQuery сэмулировать действие пользователя - как-будто бы он выбрал пункт из списка.

Comment: Для того, чтоб сэмулировать действия пользователя, достаточно `$('#status').val(needle)`. Элемент будет выбранным (выделен синим), но не будет первым в списке. Так и надо.